# Create a .txt file by converting array value as table

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js

I have an array of

`myarray = ["ram", "ram", "jan", "jan", "feb", "feb"]`

Is it possible to create a .txt file which will have this value in a table format?

Comment: You should provide in question format you are expecting. Why do you have duplicated values in array?

Comment: You want to use frontend Javascript or backend Node.js?
And what do you mean by "table format"? CSV?

Comment: Not duplicate value.. It may be username and password. Both are same in my case.

Comment: Why not using object instead of array then? I mean array of object

Comment: @Frax Table means, like a report for username & password.

Comment: @Vinod your question is unclear, improve it with concrete sample of what you are looking for

Comment: @A.Wolff Report should be in table format, having 2 columns username & password. In that, this array value to be placed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Frontend:**

If your code is going to be on the frontend (browser), you can use the following:

```
var row_width = 40;

var content = "";
content += "Username" + new Array(row_width + 1).join(" ") + "Password\n";
content += "********" + new Array(row_width + 1).join(" ") + "********\n";

for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i += 2) {
    content += myarray[i] + new Array(row_width - myarray[i].length + 9).join(" ");
    content += myarray[i+1];
    content += "\n";
}

// Build a data URI:
uri = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(content);

// Click on the file to download
// You can also do this as a button that has the href pointing to the data URI
location.href = uri;
```

Here's a link to a working frontend example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fraximus/Q8tK9/)

Name the file as something.txt.

**Backend:**

If you want to use Node.js on the backend to generate and save this file, you need to use the following:

After looping through the array and creating the 'content' string as above, you save the file as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile("/path_to_file/table.txt", content, function (err){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("File saved");
    }
});
```

I haven't tried that code yet, but feel free to let me know if it works for you. I hope that's what you need.

**NOTE** that the frontend code might not be supported by some outdated/bad browsers

Comment: It works.. Thank you but the alignment is not good,it shows like               `Username        Password********        ********ram ramjan        janfeb        feb` Can u help me on this?

Comment: This is a matter of tweaking the content string... I'll try adding tabs and newlines and will let you know.
You can modify the string as you like

Comment: I updated the code adding a "\n" newline character to the string.
Let me know if it looks better

Comment: `Username        Password********        ********ram        ram`

Comment: `jan        jan`     (next line)

Comment: `feb        feb` (next line)

Comment: Or is it possible to change the format of file form .txt to someother for better alignment?

Comment: If you want to keep it as text, you just need to get the amount of spaces right. I added more new lines. It should look better now but needs more adjustment.
We can also have the file as HTML with a table inside and some CSS rules

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47496/discussion-between-vinod-and-frax)

Comment: Re-edited the code adding a variable that serves to set the column width in the text file.
Also added a working fiddle for experimentation

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of achieving that (that depends on your final requirements and constraints). The best way would be to use some templating engine e.g. *[underscore template](http://underscorejs.org/#template)* or *[Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)*.

However you can also do it using regular JavaScript Array.

Example of returning HTML table:

```
var myarray  = ["user1", "pass1", "user2", "pass2", "user3", "pass3" ],
    output = [];
output.push('<table>')
for (var i = 0; i < myarray .length; i += 2) {
    output.push('<tr><td>')
    output.push(myarray [i])
    output.push('</td><td>')
    output.push(myarray [i+1])
    output.push('</td></tr>')
};
output.push('</table>')

// output.join('') gives you formatted HTML array
```

Output would be like (note that HTML has been formatted for better readability):

```
<table>
    <tr><td>user1</td><td>pass1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>user2</td><td>pass2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>user3</td><td>pass3</td></tr>
</table>
```

I hope that will help.